# style set wygwam

Tags: wygwam

I have defined a new set of style to use in the wygwam editor and that works fine.  I have called this file "my styles.js" and included it in /themes/third_party/wygwam_assets/
as suggested in the guide located here: http://pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/docs/style-set

One of the styles I have included is called myclass (see below) and it does get applied within the editor.  I have also included a style sheet in the same location as described in the guide that defines myclass.  The problem I have is that the styling although being applied is not showing within the editor window.

```
    CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles',
[
    // Block Styles
    { name: 'Blue Title', element: 'h2', styles: { 'color': 'Blue' } },
    { name: 'Red Title' , element: 'h3', styles: { 'color': 'Red' } },
    { name: 'My Class', element: 'div', attributes: { 'class': 'myclass' } },

    // Inline Styles
    { name: 'CSS Style', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my_style' } },

    { name: 'Marker: Yellow', element: 'span', styles: { 'background-color': 'Yellow' } }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You still need to point Wygwam to the new styleset. In Addons > Modules > Wygwam, select the configuration you want to use. Then you'll see the '*CSS File*' field. This is where you place the full path to your CSS file to be applied to the Wygwam field. Copy that in here and hit '*Update*' and you should see your styles applied.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually you will need to set the StylesSet as Ian said, but the option looks like this:

[image]

It doesn't "really" matter where the file is located, you just have to enter the path to it. I prefer using a relative path. Then be sure you have the "Styles" drop down in whichever Configuration file you are using for WYGWAM:

[image]

Then just use the styles to add whatever style to text, images, etc...

Comment: Note: for an unknown reason, I had to use an absolute path to my styles set: http://example.com/js/wygwam_styles.js - otherwise it didn't work

Comment: Shouldn't have to, a relative path like `/assets/js/wygwam.js` should work.